# SynchronousQueue Vs Exchanger

Tags: java, concurrency

Whats the difference between Exchanger and SynchronousQueue? And the scenarios in which each of them can be used? Which one is better performance wise? (Lock wise?)

Comment: Unless micro-seconds count, it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 10):

An `Exchanger` is more of a pure synchronization mechanism while a `SynchronousQueue` additionally offers all operations of a standard queue data structure. This means that you can for example check what objects are in queue, cancel scheduled but not yet executed actions by removing items from the queue asynchronously etc. - operations an `Exchanger` doesn't offer. Since many implementations allow setting a limit on queue size, you get additional control over your resource usage and can drop requests if the queue grows above a certain threshold. On the other hand, the `Exchanger` offers two-way communication out of the box while a single queue is just one way (though one can implement communication in the other direction manually). Since many practical situation require just a producers-consumers relationship, a queue is often better because of an easier to understand API and additional operations listed above.

[This article](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html?z#!/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html) describes a practical use case for `Exchanger`. They concentrate on being able to avoid creating and garbage collecting new objects when communicating between threads (depending on implementation, queues may allocate entries when you append something to them). Performance will probably depend on your particular use case. In the example they use `Exchanger` for efficiency (avoiding garbage collection), but in most cases (if you don't have to provide sub-millisecond latencies) allocating an object or two isn't such a big issue and I'd prefer using a queue for the extra control it allows.

**EDIT:** I checked the source for `Exchanger.java` in Oracle JDK and it does create temporary objects of class `Exchanger.Node` in `Exchanger.doExchange()`. So it seems that contrary to what authors of the linked article state, `Exchanger` isn't allocation-free. Neither is (rather obviously) `LinkedBlockingQueue`. The `ArrayBlockingQueue`, in contrast, doesn't allocate any temporary objects when an item is appended to it. It only allocates an array to hold the maximum allowed number of elements when it is created, but that's just a one-time operation. During use, it doesn't create new objects, so from the pure GC point of view it should be better than `Exchanger`.

Comment: Thanks Michal. Can you please elaborate how does Exchanger avoid creating and garbage collecting new objects? Is it that queues allocate/deallocate objects for new Nodes and Exchangers simply help in exchange of references?

Comment: The Exchanger, exchanges an object each between two threads.  This means you can have two data structures passed back and forth which can be reused again and again.  If this is a large or expensive object, e.g. a ByteBuffer, this can make a SynchronousQueue impractical.

Comment: @Hemanshu A queue may need wrappers, for example a `LinkedBlockingQueue` needs `Node` objects which hold their payloads plus references to next linked items. An `ArrayBlockingQueue` doesn't need such a wrapper, but in contrast to `LinkedBlockingQueue` it must allocate an array for its maximum size beforehand. It's a one-time operation, so no issue usually, but yes, it's an alloc. So a queue may, but does not have to, cause extra allocation each item. Now, I checked the code for `Exchanger` and it actually does create temporary `Node` objects. The authors of the article seem to be plain wrong.

Comment: @PeterLawrey A queue doesn't clone the object stored in it, it's just passing references, so it can as well be used to pass the same object between threads. `Exchanger` has the advantage of being two-way, though, so I guess that's where the profit is. But both some queues and `Exchanger` create some temporary objects due to their internal workings.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski Exchanger has the advantage of being able passing the same two objects around and around. It doesn't need any temporary objects and thus avoids garbage being created. LinkedBlockingQueue creates a node each time it has to wait, and it doesn't help you recycle the objects you place in the queue.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I checked the source for `Exchanger.java` and it does create temporary objects of class `Exchanger.Node` in `Exchanger.doExchange()`

Comment: @MichałKosmulski Good point.  When I have used it in the past, I had been exchanging large objects, not so often which could explain why it didn't show up as an issue.

Comment: This is misleading. `SynchronousQueue` doesn't actually implement any queue-like operation in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's focus on the key point..

- Exchanger: Is a rendezvous point where two threads can exchange objects
- SynchQueue: Is a queue! One thread puts and waits, until another thread pops.. there is no exchange business here

Exchanger is a kind of bidirectional SyncQueue